# What comment convention is //[<module>_includes ... //]?

Tags: c++, comments

The [boost::property_tree tutorial](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/property_tree/examples/debug_settings.cpp) includes an apparent comment convention:

```
//[debug_settings_includes
#include ...
//]
//[debug_settings_data
struct debug_settings {...};
//]
//[debug_settings_load
void debug_settings::load(const std::string &filename) {...}
//]
//[debug_settings_save
void debug_settings::save(const std::string &filename) {...}
//]
int main() {...}
```

Is it just an emacs org-mode convention? Are there tools that leverage this convention? Will adopting and embracing it fulfill my life?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be part of the documentation generation.

for example if you see [the raw source for the tutorial documentation](https://github.com/boostorg/property_tree/blob/develop/doc/tutorial.qbk) you will see that includes lines such as

```
First we need some includes:

[debug_settings_includes]

To store the logging configuration in the program we create a debug_settings
structure:

[debug_settings_data]
```

The square-bracket surrounded lines have corresponding sections in [the example source file](https://github.com/boostorg/property_tree/blob/develop/examples/debug_settings.cpp).

And when looking in [the documentation itself](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/property_tree/tutorial.html) we see that those "keywords" have been replaced by the code from the source file.

For more information read [the Boost quickbook documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/quickbook.html).